# Firebase / Firestore - Are there any specific cookies that are used that need to be referenced in a privacy policy?

Tags: firebase, cookies, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web app that uses Firestore for data and Firebase Storage for images. After an account creation (which occurs via an iOS app), the user can sign into the web app and add new items and new images. However, upon reading cookie policies, it appears that I'll need to inform the user if the site uses any particular cookies - [Cookie consent banner](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/cookie-consent-banner/)

I haven't actively added any cookies into the web app. It's purely using AngularFire and Firebase to allow the user to authenticate and interact.

The cookie site link above states the following:

```
To be compliant, the cookie notice should be one component of a cookie management 
solution for your website, that takes care of the following tasks:

1. To provide the website users with specific and accurate information on all 
cookies and other tracking technologies in use on the website.

2. To give the users the possibility to opt in and opt out of the various 
types of cookies, and to have access to their settings and make subsequent changes
to them if they change their mind.

3. To make sure that the user consent is requested prior to the setting of cookies
in the users' browsers.

4. To make sure that the website functions properly even though the user has chosen
to opt out of all but the strictly necessary cookies.

5. To keep a record of all given consents for documentation, and to make sure that
this documentation is securely stored.

6. Ask for renewed consent every 12 months upon the user's 
first revisit to the site.
```

Are there any specific cookies that Firebase / Firestore use that I would need to explicitly outline to my potential users?

Answer (score 1):

I might be really late but here is what I found after having the same issues. Anyway, the short answer is by default of what you have is what the info below says.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

This is an excerpt from that page

> Firebase Auth provides server-side session cookie management for
>   traditional websites that rely on session cookies. This solution has
>   several advantages over client-side short-lived ID tokens, which may
>   require a redirect mechanism each time to update the session cookie on
>   expiration:
>
> - Improved security via JWT-based session tokens that can only be
>     generated using authorized service accounts.
> - Stateless session cookies
>     that come with all the benefit of using JWTs for authentication. The
>     session cookie has the same claims (including custom claims) as the ID
>     token, making the same permissions checks enforceable on the session
>     cookies.
> - Ability to create session cookies with custom expiration
>     times ranging from 5 minutes to 2 weeks.
> - Flexibility to enforce cookie
>     policies based on application requirements: domain, path, secure,
>     httpOnly, etc.
> - Ability to revoke session cookies when token theft is
>     suspected using the existing refresh token revocation API. Ability to
>     detect session revocation on major account changes.

If you would read on that page there are other info on how to configure more. I hope someone can answer more on this.